Meditation brings no joy just calm
When I meditate I never feel any sense of happiness, bliss or joy. I I just feel calm but not so good that I want to continue for more than an hour. Am I missing something?

Can you describe your meditation procedure? As my experience, Quick Vipassana (like 5 or 10min) then Maithree meditation is the most happy bringing meditation sequence. Just doing Vipassana doesn't bring happiness until very close to Nirvana. (Vipassana brings truth).

The feeling of joy begins to appear as mental activity decreases. Merely sitting still or merely following a practice isn't sufficient to produce it; the aim of practice is to get the mind to release. If you want an analogy, imagine that you've gone to see an intense action film. At the end of the film, you suddenly realize that you've spent the last hour and a half clenching your jaw, gripping the armrests, and sucking in your breath, so you open your hands, shake out your head, take a deep breath, and let feeling flow back into your body. That's what the human mind is like: always in the grip of 'doing', clenching like a fist around any thought or imagining. Once you become aware of how much activity your mind is up to you can take steps to let it go, and once it lets go all the energy it had tied up in 'doing' is released back into pure consciousness.
Remember, getting the mind to let go isn't something you can 'do' or 'force', because 'doing' and 'forcing' are also activities of the mind that the mind will get hung up on. You just have to be aware that the mind is 'doing', and remind yourself that nothing the mind is doing is relevant, necessary, or important in that moment. Meditation practice is like singing a lullaby to a fussy, fretful baby; you don't get the fruits of it until the baby goes to sleep.

In Buddhism, there are 2 types of meditation.

Vipassana - understanding the true nature of the reality
Samatha - development of concentration of the mind

Vipassana brings happiness by reducing the attachment/Thanha to material or nun material objects.
Reaching Nirvana is the fullest state of this ultimate happiness.
Samatha brings happiness by,

attaching the mind to the focus object and satisfying with fulfilling this attachment
reducing 5 hindrances and reducing suffering generated out of these hindrances.

Reaching jhana is the fullest state of this happiness and this happiness is just satisfying the mind. (not an ultimate happiness).

Quick Vipassana (like 5 or 10 minutes) then Maithree(Samatha) meditation is the most happy-bringing meditation sequence according to my experience. Just doing Vipassana doesn't bring happiness until very close to Nirvana. (Vipassana brings truth).

Yes. The Buddha describes the very first level of concentration - the first jhāna - as comprising of pervasive pleasure and bliss entirely filling and suffusing the body - AN 5:28. He consistently depicts the higher levels of jhāna as following on from this one. If you haven't experienced this then you likely haven't tasted right concentration, which the Buddha teaches to be the path to awakening - it sits at the pinnacle of the eightfold path, with all other factors its mere "requisites and supports" - MN 117. Only at the fourth jhāna does perfect equanimity arise, abandoning happiness and distress: nevertheless it is still described as being even more pleasant than the jhānas that precede it (DN 2), as well as being the point where the mind and body are so calm that the in-and-out breaths cease - DN 34. These are all states that are taught to give higher pleasure and bliss than any sensual pleasure. Therefore if you haven't attained them you're missing something very important from the point of view of the Dhamma. Even if you have attained them but don't want to stay in them for a long time, you're likely missing how valuable and important these states are. As the Buddha said, the attainment of nibbāna - the highest bliss - depends on them - AN 9:36.

The suttas contain two types of meditation with rapture:

Anapanasati (MN 118), which includes a lower lever of rapture, experienced while cognizant of the in & out breathing.

Jhana, which includes a higher level of rapture, with no experience of breathing. Jhana only has five factors (MN 43), none of which are the breathing.


To reach the rapture of Anapanasati, there generally needs to be constant awareness of breathing, with a open quiet non-forceful mind, for around 75 minutes.
To reach jhana generally requires months of continuously developing Anapanasati in a monastic/retreat setting. Note: there are no Jhana Evangelists on the internet who have actually attained jhana. These Jhana Evangelists have over-estimated their trivial meditation experiences.
In conclusion, to reach the basic rapture level of Anapanasati requires having a calm contented meditation for over one hour.
Importantly, ignore posts in the internet about "jhana". There is much calm & joy to be found in Anapanasati, which is not yet on the level of jhana.

It should be noted that the breath - included in the four satipaṭṭhāna - is explicitly described to be an object for the four jhānas (synonymous with the faculty of concentration in the suttas): “Now what is concentration, lady, what qualities are its themes, what qualities are its requisites, and what is its development?”
“Singleness of mind is concentration, friend Visākha; the four establishings of mindfulness are its themes; the four right exertions are its requisites; and any cultivation, development, & pursuit of these qualities is its development.”

Note too that development of the satipaṭṭhāna is explicitly here equated to the development of concentration i.e. jhāna. Since first jhāna includes thinking and evaluation it obviously can contain thinking about the breathing. Similarly since second and third jhānas involve singleness of mind - and are described as "perception attainments" they can, too, with their single perception being the breathing. There's thus no reason to believe jhāna blots out awareness of the breathing - particularly form jhāna which of course is based on perception of form.

These comments are wrong and best deleted. Thank you
